# unable to log into database using oracle.apex.APEXExport class

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle11gr2, ora-01017

I need to perform batch export of several APEX applications into .sql script. I am trying to use Oracle's unsupported (though packaged with 11g server) Java utility in question.

I have two database instances. Both of them are 11gR2 XE. 
One is running on my local VMWare machine for testing puproses, another one is running on remote APEX hosting.

The problem is, I cannot connect to latter instance. That's how I run it:

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=us oracle.apex.APEXExport -db my.hosting.net:1521:xe -user scott -password tiger -applicationid 101
```

And that's the error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied                                                                                       

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)                                                                                                      
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330)                                                                                                                   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:282)                                                                                                                   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:277)                                                                                                                   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:791)                                                                                               
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:363)                                                                                                                  
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:453)                                                                                                       
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:164)                                                                                                                 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:34)                                                                                                 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:753)                                                                                                                  
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                            
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                            
    at oracle.apex.APEXExport.main(APEXExport.java:316)
```

The funny thing is, I encounter no issues connecting to the very same schema using SQL*Plus.

And I also have absolutely no problems exporting applications from my local VMWare-based instance.

Any ideas of the direction I should look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if anyone else encounters the same issue... 
It helped when I issued `alter user scott identified by tiger;` where `tiger` was *current* password. So, basically, I just refreshed password and for some reason it all started to work.